# JS script only works while I don't change the current page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm creating a web project in Ruby on Rails. I have a `main.js` file stored inside `/app/assets/javascripts/`, in which I've developed a little script to reset the forms.

The script works perfectly just while I don't surf around the web. If I change the current page, the script doesn't work anymore. To get it work again, I have to reload the page through the browser (using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>).

The `main.js` script is supposed to be compiled and it should be available in all the pages in the project, isn't it?

What's wrong?

The code in `main.js`:

```
// Get rid of data in forms
jQuery.fn.reset = function () {
$(this).find("input, textarea, select").each (function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        if (!$(this).is(':hidden') && !$(this).is(':submit')) $(this).val('');
    }
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Cancel button in forms
    $(".cancel").click(function() {
        $(document).reset();
    })
});
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_directory .
```

Comment: what does your application.js manifest file look like?

Comment: Added to the main post.

Comment: Turbolinks is the culprit. 

See [my answer to similar question][1] earlier today... 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links/18770589#18770589

Comment: Correct, the answer is in that post. Thanks a lot for so quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbolinks is the "problem". `$(document.ready` is only triggered on full page reloads. You need to also listen for `$(document).on('page:load', ...)`

See comment #3 on OP (above).

Comment: Aaah. Apparently if your "answer" has a link back to SO it'll become a comment and not an answer. So my answer is actually comment #3 on OP.